# Denormalize an attribute value - Convert a camelcased value to dash-delimited value

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I was creating a directive in angularjs. In `link` I tried to get attributes with `attrs`. They were all been normalized to camelcasing form. But I wanted to reinsert them back to some other element. So **I wanted to convert camelCased value to dash-delimited value**. i.e. **`Denormalize`** value. Is there any simple way in angular js to do this.

```
module.directive('myDirective', function(){
    return {
        'link': function(scope, element, attr, controller){
            ....
            var newElement = jQuery("<div></div>");
            for(var key in attr){
                newElement.attr(attr[key]);   // !newElement will not keep dashes in attribute 
                                              // i.e. dashes will be removed from attributes
            }
        }
    };
});
```

I could normalize a dash-delimited value to camelCased value, But what should I do to denormalize them.
So here my actual problem is to **preserve dashes in attribute**

Answer (score 0):

There is `$attr` inside `attr`. `$attr` contains information about original attribute names and normalised, so when you have normalised attribute name - you can access to original name by `attr.$attr[normalisedAttrName]`.

And don't forget simple check

`if (key.charAt(0) == '$' || attr.hasOwnProperty(key)) { continue; }`

For your example:

```
...
for(var key in attr){
  newElement.attr(attr.$attr[key], attr[key]);
}
...
```